# WHMCS server status, uptime and server load, not available

Tags: server, whmcs, server-load, uptime-monitoring

I am using whmcs 7.0.1, but in server status, uptime and server load, show me **not available.**

I have set in whmcs admin Setup > Products/Services > Servers > edit, in "Server Status Address" add the path "http://www.myserverdomain.gr/status/"

Server name : work,
HTTP: work,
FTP: work,
POP3: work,
PHP INFO: work,
server load: **not availiable**,
Uptime: **not availiable**

When i type in my brower "http://www.myserverdomain.gr/status/" i show the values (server load & uptime), but in "http://www.myserverdomain.gr/serverstatus.php" show me **"Not availiable"**

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by downloading the latest whmcs status version. The old one had that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

I remove from .htaccess the line with
"**require valid-user**".